# Is there a way to ignore certain keys with Decodable just extract their values?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable, decodable

I have the following JSON example

```
    let json = """
    {
        "str": [
            {
            "abv": "4.4",
            "weight": "4.1",
                "volume": "5.0"
        }
        ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!
```

And the following `Decoable` structs

```
    struct Outer: Decodable {
        let stri: [Garten]
        
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case stri = "str"
        }
        
        
        struct Garten: Decodable {
            let alcoholByVol: String
            let weight: String
            let vol: String
            
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
                case alcoholByVol = "abv"
                case weight = "weight"
                case vol = "volume"
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to know if there is any way to avoid the outer `struct`. It is basically only present for that one key to decode the inner array.

This is how I am currently decoding this

`let attrs = try! decoder.decode(Outer.self, from: json)`

But I am curious if there is something similar to

`let attrs = try! decoder.decode([[String: [Outer]].self, from: json)`

Comment: Yes you can but there is one [ to much

Comment: You also need to replace `Outer` with `Outer.Garten` like: `let attrs = try! decoder.decode([String: [Outer.Garten]].self, from: json)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `Outer` completely and decode a `[String: [Garten]].self`. Then get the value associated with the `"str"` key:

```
let attrsDict = try! decoder.decode([String: [Garten]].self, from: json)
let attrs = attrsDict["str"]!
```

You can wrap this in a function:

```
func decodeNestedObject<T: Codable>(_ type: T.Type, key: String, 
    from data: Data, using decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) throws -> T {
    try decoder.decode([String: T].self, from: data)[key]!
}
```

Usage:

```
let attrs = try decodeNestedObject([Garten].self, key: "str", from: data)
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sure I tried this suggestion before but for some reason it works now. Appreciate the help a lot.